# rsync not copying all files and folders

Tags: cron, web, rsync, remote-server

Using rsync in cron to copy all files from a web server to a remote server using the following command

```
rsync -arvzh /home/foldername/* root@***.***.***.***:/home/foldername>> /var/log/filename`date +%d%m%y`.log 2>&1
```

This works fine for all folders and files used by ftpuser and ftpgroup

However if any files or folders are added by www-data it does not copy or sync them.

How can i get it to copy all files and folders recursivly no matter who owns them please
Many thanks
P

Comment: Although this is not an SO question, as which user do you run this command?

Comment: As root for both servers with the normal security sigantures in place

Comment: what is the content of `/var/log/filenameDDMMYYY.log` after a failed run. I suspect that the rsync is failing due to the restricted environment of cron.